# Java reflection: Class.getConstructor throws NoSuchMethodException but Class.getConstructors finds the correct constructor

Tags: java, reflection, constructor

I'm attempting to use reflection to create a new instance of a class, using `Class.getConstructor`, like so:

```
class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // this throws NoSuchMethodException
        Constructor<Point> constructor = Point.class.getConstructor(float.class, float.class);

        // but this finds the method
        Constructor<Point>[] constructors = (Constructor<Point>[])Point.class.getConstructors();
        System.out.println(constructors[0].toString()); // public Point(float,float)
    }
}

class Point {
    public float x, y;

    public Point(float x, float y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Why can't I get the constructor by supplying argument types?

Comment: Is `Point` an inner class?  What happens if you declare it `static`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is fine. You just need to handle the [checked exception](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catchOrDeclare.html) by catching it:

```
try {
    Constructor<Point> constructor = Point.class.getConstructor(float.class, float.class);
} catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
    System.out.println("missing constructor");
}
```

Or declare it in the method signature:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchMethodException {
```